How to run Abaqus Script in no-GUI mode with using display group APIs
I am creating an Abaqus script to get image for max stress and strain of parts across each time increment.
Script should open odb files in Abaqus Viewer in no-GUI mode and find out in which time increment each part has max stress and strain, and get an image output of the same. For getting the max values I am using Report-> Field output option API [session.writeFieldReport()]
My script is working fine in GUI mode but not in Non-GUI. May be beacause I have used displayGroupOdbToolset library.
Can anyone please help me to modify the code so that it may work in non-GUI mode.
Following is my code to get max result values for each part.
#############################################
from abaqus import *
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo
import odbAccess
from abaqusConstants import *
import odbSection
import visualization
import os
import platform
import shutil

# get results
def getResultsFromODB(odbPath, odbName):
    # open odb
    odbPath = os.path.join(odbDir, odbName)
    odb = odbAccess.openOdb(path=odbPath)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=odb)
    allframe = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames
    leaf = dgo.Leaf(leafType=DEFAULT_MODEL)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.displayGroup.replace(leaf=leaf)
    # filter parts which have "_3D" as suffix in their name
    allElemSets = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].elementSets.keys()
    sets_3D = []
    p = 0
    while p < len(allElemSets):
        x = allElemSets[p]
        p += 1
        if x[-3:] == '_3D':
            name = 'PART-1-1.' + x
            name = str(name)
            sets_3D.append(name)
    # log('getting data from parts...')
    # displaying parts one by one to export *.rpt file to get max values of results in each increments
    session.fieldReportOptions.setValues(printXYData=OFF, printTotal=OFF)
    for name in sets_3D:
        # log(name)
        leaf = dgo.LeafFromElementSets(elementSets=(name, ))
        session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.displayGroup.replace(leaf=leaf)
        outFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(odbDir, name)) + '.rpt'
        session.writeFieldReport(fileName=outFile, append=ON, 
                sortItem='Node Label', odb=odb, step=(len(odb.steps)-1), frame=(len(allframe)-1), outputPosition=NODAL, 
                variable=(('LE', INTEGRATION_POINT, ((INVARIANT, 'Max. Principal'), )), (
                'S', INTEGRATION_POINT, ((INVARIANT, 'Mises'), (INVARIANT, 
                'Max. Principal'), )), ), stepFrame=ALL)
    # reading max values from *.rpt file and exporting into *.csv file
    result = []
    for name in sets_3D:
        lst_resultValues = readTextFile((os.path.join(odbDir, name)) + '.rpt')
        data = str(name) + ',' + str(lst_resultValues[0][0]) + ',' + str(lst_resultValues[0][1]) + ',' + str(lst_resultValues[0][2]) +\
        ',' + str(lst_resultValues[1][0]) + ',' + str(lst_resultValues[1][1]) + ',' + str(lst_resultValues[1][2]) +\
        ',' + str(lst_resultValues[2][0]) + ',' + str(lst_resultValues[2][1]) + ',' + str(lst_resultValues[2][2])
        result.append(data)
    # log('exporting results to CSV...')
    OutFileName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(odbName))[0]
    export_CSV( os.path.abspath(os.path.join(odbDir, OutFileName)) + '.csv' , result)
    # log('Done')
    session.odbs[odbPath].close()

getResultsFromODB(odbDir, odbName)


You can use noGUI option in cmd or Powershell or Linux Terminal as follows:
If you want to Abaqus CAE and Viewer functionality:
abaqus cae noGUI=<script name>
If you want to Abaqus Viewer functionality:
abaqus viewer noGUI=<script name>
Also, certain GUI commands where a window pop-up required will not work when using noGUI option.
Please navigate to the folder where your script is present in cmd or PowerShell before using above commands.

Thanks for your suggestion. I have used these for noGUI options, but my script is not working. It shows error that displayGroupOdbToolset not found. The same scripts works well in GUI mode. But the request is for nonGUI mode. Please suggest.

As I said, GUI related commands will not work in noGUI mode. You have to GUI mode in order to use these features.

If you want to just ouptut the data into a text file, then there is a possible way. However, you can only output the elemental data at integration points, elemental nodes and at elemental centroid AND not at nodes. 
You can make use of:
getSubset - to get the subset of result data for a region (element set/node set/etc.) or a location (integration points/centroid/etc.)
getScalarField - to access the invariants of vector or tensor quantities, for ex, Max Principal, Mises, etc..
bulkDataBlocks - get the data as numpy array.
elset_name = 'some set name'
instance_name = 'PART-1-1'
step_name = 'some step name'
frame_indx = -1
odb = session.odbs[odbname]
# Access element set object from odb
if elset_name in odb.rootAssembly.elementSets:
    elset = odb.rootAssembly.elementSets[elset_name]
else:
    elset = odb.rootAssembly.instances[instance_name].elementSets[elset_name]

# Access the data for interested element set
eldata = odb.steps[step_name].frames[frame_indx].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(region=elset)

# Write data to a text file
fout = open('output_data.dat', 'w')
for bulk_data in eldata.bulkDataBlocks:
    data = numpy.vstack((bulk_data.elementLabels,
                         bulk_data.integrationPoints, bulk_data.data.T))
    title_str = ['Elm No.', 'Int Point'] + list(bulk_data.componentLabels)

    numpy.savetxt(fout, [title_str], fmt='%12s %12s %18s %18s %18s %18s %18s %18s')
    numpy.savetxt(fout, data.T, fmt='%12d %12d %18.6e %18.6e %18.6e %18.6e %18.6e %18.6e ')

fout.close()

